# How to get custom model from Firestore data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserProfileModel: Identifiable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let username: String
    let fullname: String
    let profileImageUrl: String
    let email: String
}


struct UserService {
    
    func fetchUser(withUid uid: String) {
        print("DEBUG: Fetch user info")
//        print("DEBUG: User info og uid \(uid)")
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot?.data()
            else {
                print("user not printed")
                return
            }
            print("DEBUG: User data is \(snapshot)")
            
            guard let user = try? snapshot.data(as: UserProfileModel.self)
            else {
                print("user not printed \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("DEBUG: Username is \(user.username)")
            print("DEBUG: Email is \(user.email)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
guard let snapshot = snapshot?.data()
```

In snapshot I will get current user data.

but in this line

```
guard let user = try? snapshot.data(as: UserProfileModel.self)
```

when I print this user then null print ho Raha ha
but I want same snapshot data as a UserProfileModel object

Comment: Don't use `try ?`. Use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` in your `catch`. Right now you are just throwing away any errors

Comment: my issue is  not getting user data that store in firebase

Comment: It is unable to map the document to the struct you have specified, but why it is unable to do this you don't know because you are throwing away the error that would probably tell you. Don't use `try ?`